# Can't find element located by By.xpath

Tags: python, java, selenium, xpath, automation

i tried to click this button with xpath, classname, and css locator. I even put a time wait so it can load properly first, but nothing worked. still can't click the button, please help.

```
<div class="relative create-disbursement-dropdown" size="small">

<button data-v-a7f43302="" type="button" variant="solid" color="green" size="small" lefticon="" righticon="" options="[object Object],[object Object]" class="
    relative
    box-border
    transition-all
    duration-200
    font-sans font-semibold
    rounded-semi
    py-2
    disabled:pointer-events-none
    disabled:cursor-default
    focus:outline-none
   btn-small btn-solid btn-green"><div data-v-a7f43302="" class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-2">

<div data-v-a7f43302="" class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-2"><!---->

<span data-v-a7f43302=""> Create Disbursement </span>

</div>
</button>
</div>
```

[this is the button looks like]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cml4u.png

**my code was like this one:**

```
WebElement createDisburseButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"disbursement-root\"]/div/div[1]/div/button")));

createDisburseButton.click();
```

**the error:**

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="disbursement-root"]/div/div[1]/div/button (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Comment: To be able to help, please provide the executed code (java class) that is failing, a more expanded DOM and a substantial stacktrace in relation to the issue. With the information provided currently, there is nothing to go on what the issue might be. Also provide a link to the webpage, if that is not available as it is internal, please provide a screenshot of what you are expecting to click, also showing the inspect of that button with the DOM via the F12 option

Comment: What is the error you ran into ?

Comment: i edited the description guys, appreciate the help @djmonki

Comment: i edited the description guys, appreciate the help @cruisepandey

Comment: @Clara : Please see below my answer .

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>Create Disbursement</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Create Disbursement')]")).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Create Disbursement')]").click()
  ```

Comment: still not worked using java . I put 

`Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println("disburse homepage fully loaded");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Create Disbursement')]")).click();`

and still got `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(., 'Create Disbursement')]"}`

Comment: tagging you ^ @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//span[contains(text(),'Create Disbursement')]/ancestor::button
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This div is not under an iframe.
2. This div is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

If you are sure that we have 1/1 matching node, and above 3 conditions did not meet.

Then you can use the below code trial.

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//span[contains(text(),'Create Disbursement')]/ancestor::button
```

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Create Disbursement')]/ancestor::button").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Create Disbursement')]/ancestor::button"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Create Disbursement')]/ancestor::button")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Create Disbursement')]/ancestor::button")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: I've been tried all your code trial but none worked sorry :( I asked my developer he said i need to see the log of the HTML to get access to the child. I don't know what he means but guess I need to search how to do that @cruisepandey

Comment: But I appreciate all your answers tho, can't thank you enough

Comment: What is the error for first code trial ?